# Spring boot mongodb not saving uniqueId

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I'm working on a Spring application and I'm using MongoDB as my database. I have a document structure where I am saving the id of another document to use as a reference. This id is an objectId and then save it using

```
mongoOperations.save(message)
```

It is using the same objectId as the one I'm saving for reference to create _id field for this newly created document. So my document is like this

```
{
   "_id":{
      "$oid":"610a03578c9e4937107b6501"
   },
   "ConversationId":{
      "$oid":"610a03578c9e4937107b6501"
   },
   "Author":"author",
   "Body":"hey there",
   "CreatedAt":{
      "$date":{
         "$numberLong":"1628171556888"
      }
   }
}
```

As you can see that both the ids for _id and ConversationId are the same. I have tried saving ConversationId as a string and it still does the same. Not sure what mistake I'm making.

```
{
   "_id":{
      "$oid":"610a03578c9e4937107b6501"
   },
   "ConversationId": "610a03578c9e4937107b6501",
   "Author":"author",
   "Body":"hey there",
   "CreatedAt":{
      "$date":{
         "$numberLong":"1628171556888"
      }
   }
}
```

This is my model class

```
@Document(collection = "messages")
public class Message {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Field("ConversationId")
    private String conversationId;

    @Field("Author")
    private String author;

    @Field("Body")
    private String body;

    @Field("CreatedAt")
    private Instant createdAt;

}
```

COnversationId in the above model class id an objectId and I tried saving it as a string as mentioned above so It was set to type String here. I have also tried making it ObjectId and still the same issue persists.

How to make it create a unique _id for each record and not use conversationId as its id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change **id** to **_id**. Attaching reference below

```
@Document(collection = "messages")
public class Message {
    
    private String _id;

    @Field("ConversationId")
    private String conversationId;

    @Field("Author")
    private String author;

    @Field("Body")
    private String body;

    @Field("CreatedAt")
    private Instant createdAt;

}
```

Comment: No worries @Srikar